# Чтение блоков данных из потока

Tags: c++

```
int x;
while(input_stream >> x)
 my_vector.push_back(x);
```

Если во входном потоке `input_stream` встретился символ, не являющийся числом (`,` или `;`), то чтение прекратится. Как после этого можно продолжить чтение целых чисел? Правильно ли я делаю ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < blocks_number; ++i) {
  while (input_stream >> x)
    my_vector.push_back(x);

  input_stream.clear();
  input_stream.sync();
  input_stream.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Может попробуете пользоваться функциями getch() и unget(), которые получают char из буфера/возвращают, далее проверяете - если цифра (например, с помощью, is_number), то возвращаете в буфер символ и считываете число, иначе просто пропускаете и переходите на следующую итерацию.